# ExpandableListView shows nothing

Tags: java, android

No errors, no warnings, it compiles successfully, but my ExpandableListView is not showing anything.
Here is my ExpandableListViewAdapter class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}


}
```

Here is my ListViewtest class:

```
public class ListViewTest extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // get the listview
   // expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    View explist = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_expandable_list,null,false );
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) explist.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);



    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list);

}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyonone tell me where the problem my be ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override all layout changes by calling this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list);
```

This might fix the problem:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);



    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: U will get a null pointer exception when you get the listview just with " expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);" because the ExpandableListView is in another layout,

Comment: Oh, I won't just try the solution, I am sure it should work

Comment: U will get an exception because it will say, it can't find the  ExpandableListView. We are in ListViewTest class, which is not "connected" to any layout, so we have to use LayoutInflater in order to get the ListView

Comment: findViewById works recursive, you know? So it'll find views in sub-layouts. Post your .xml, probably I missed something

Comment: Shit man, it really worked, I was doing the same few days ago and it didn't work, probably missed something. I Love youu!!!

Answer (score 0):

Focus on following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list);
```

Here `R.layout.activity_expandable_list` is just an `int`. so you need to set to view object.
Try:

```
View root = binding.getRoot();
setContentView(root);
```